# change the name of the array at run time

Tags: c#

In my scenario, I'm fetching all data from a web table and storing it in an array. Each array holds one row data.

My problem here is, I want to create a new array with a new name for each iteration. So that the data in first row is stored in one array. When the second row data is fetched , a New array should be created and the data has to be stored in the newly created array.

I'm using c# language.

Here is my code

```
        IWebElement table = _Browser.FindElementById("", "gview_jqGrid");
        IList<IWebElement> rowCollections = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        int RowCnt = rowCollections.Count;
        String[] DataArray = new String[RowCnt];
        foreach (IWebElement row in rowCollections)
        {

               IList<IWebElement> colCollection = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
                foreach (IWebElement col in colCollection)
                {
                    String Data = col.Text;
                    // ------ Here I want a array to store data. A new array for each Iteration
                    j++;
                }
          }
```

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at [multi-dimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)?

Comment: what do you mean by a new name? I think what you need is an array of arrays aka 2d array.

Comment: Could you use a 2D array - you can't dynamically change the name of an array but you can assign the data to a new region of memory which has the same effect. so `myarray[0][]` is the one from the first iteration, `myarray[1][]` from the second, etc.

Comment: I still strongly think he should use a data class that holds one row each

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list of array:

```
List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>();
```

and you have an array

```
int[] intArray = new int[5];
```

than you can put those arrays into your list.

```
arrayList.Add(intArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the rows will be, just create a class that contains the row data, then create a class, and push it into your array each time you retrieve a row

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a different data structure, like a 2D array or a hashtable/dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You should use a multi-dimensional array.  The array declaration would look something like this:

```
object[,] table = new object[10, 10];
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=vs.110).aspx

If you don't know how big it will get than you probably want a list of arrays.  Assuming 10 columns:

```
List<object[]> table = new List<object[]>();
var row = new object[10];
// populate row array here...
table.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to give a name to your arrays, use a dictionary:

```
var arrays = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();

while (rows available) {
    var a = new int[10];
    FillArrayFromRow(a, row);
    string name = GetNameFrom(row);
    arrays.Add(name, a);
}
```

You can access a named array like this

```
int[] x = arrays["a name"];
```